# How to Read 20 bit integer in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In **JavaScript**
I am having a variable of 20 bit(16287008619584270370) and I want to convert it into binary of 64 bit but when I used the binary conversion code(Mentioned below) then it doesn't show me real binary of 64 bit.

```
var tag = 16287008619584270370;
var binary = parseInt(tag, 10).toString(2);
```

After dec2bin code implementation:

```
-1110001000000111000101000000110000011000000010111011000000000000
```

The correct binary should be:

```
-1110001000000111000101000000110000011000000010111011000011000010
```

(last 8 binary changed)

When I checked the problem then I get to know that code only reads the variable up to 16 bit after that it assumes 0000 and shows the binary of this (16287008619584270000).

So finally i need a code from anywhere that convert my  whole 20 bit number into its actual binary in java Script.

Comment: Give a read to this article: http://2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html

Comment: You don't actually have a variable with the value you think.  Do `console.log(tag)` and you'll see the problem is not when you convert to binary.

Comment: Your use of the term "bit" is misleading. I think you mean "digit", at least when you refer to decimal numbers

Comment: Did you check what `console.log(16287008619584270370)` outputs? Where did the 370 go? :-) Your problem is with the input, not with the output. JS cannot represent such numbers, so they are not even stored as you specify them in the code. You'll have to revert to strings and a BigNumber library.

Comment: The `parseInt(tag, 10)` would only make sense if `tag` was a string (but doesn't change anything of the original problem mentioned in the comments above).

Answer (score 4):

The problem arises because of the limited precision of 64-bit floating point representation. Already when you do:

```
var tag = 16287008619584270370;
```

... you have lost precision. If you output that number you'll notice it will be 370 less. JS cannot represent the given number in its number data type.

You can use the BigNumber library (or the many alternatives):

```js
const tag = BigNumber("16287008619584270370");
console.log(tag.toString(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bignumber.js/8.0.1/bignumber.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure to pass large numbers as strings, as otherwise you already lose precision even before you started.

#### Future

At the time of writing the proposal for a [native `BigInt`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint) is at stage 3, *"`BigInt` has been shipped in Chrome and is underway in Node, Firefox, and Safari."*

That change includes a language extension introducing `BigInt` literals that have an "n" suffix:

```
var tag = 16287008619584270370n;
```

Answer (score 1):

To read more than 16 chars we use BigInt instead of int.

```js
var tag = BigInt("16287008619584270370"); // as string
var binary = tag.toString(2);

console.log(binary);
```

Comment: Did you check whether this produces the expected result?

Comment: The converter you link to has the same limitation as the OP is facing.

Comment: I've modified the code so it works now, without a 3rd party library.

Comment: Please take into account that, as of today, BigInt does not seem to be implemented yet in Firefox or Edge (let alone Internet Explorer). It works in Chrome though, at least the desktop edition.